# R: Make Each Element of a List into a Column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am using the R programming language.

I have the following input ("input"):

```
> input
$coords
        x         y 
-85.70288  35.41780 

> str(input)
List of 1
 $ coords: Named num [1:2] -85.70288 35.41780
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "x" "y"

> dput(input)
list(coords = c(x = -85.70288, y = 35.41780))
```

**I would like to convert this into a data frame with two columns. For example:**

```
> input
          x       y
1 -85.70288 35.4178
```

I tried the following code - but this did not work:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(input), nrow=length(input), byrow=TRUE))
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `t(data.frame(list(coords = c(x = -85.70288, y = 35.41780))))`

Comment: @AndreWildberg that will result in a matrix. But I think `as.data.frame(t(input$coords))` may do it.

Comment: How did you get the `coords` object in the first place? There may be a way to do this at the source.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(t(input[["coords"]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert the `coords` vector to a list, after which it can be passed to e.g. `data.frame()` or `as.data.frame()`:

```
data.frame(as.list(input$coords))
#>           x       y
#> 1 -85.70288 35.4178

as.data.frame(as.list(input$coords))
#>           x       y
#> 1 -85.70288 35.4178
```

Or similarly, to create a `tibble`:

```
dplyr::as_tibble(as.list(input$coords))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 -85.7  35.4
```

Or a `data.table`:

```
data.table::as.data.table(as.list(input$coords))
#>            x       y
#> 1: -85.70288 35.4178
```